# PrivId C# SDK - Get Results That Are Printed In Console

Tags: c#, console, barcode, fhe, privateid

I am using PrivID C# SDK to get barcode from a driver license.

This is the code I use to get the barcode:

```
var isvalid = privid_fhe_face1.is_valid(
    Image.Load(imagePath), 
    (int)privid_fhe_face.nContextEnum.IdBarcodeRGB);
            
isvalid.OutputResults(
    imagePath, 
    out_filder + "barcode" + isvalid.result + ".bmp");
```

The barcode is printed in the console, but I can't find a way to get the string of the barcode to further process it in the application.

Is there a way to get it?

Comment: You can do a screen capture and get a bmp.  Then use code at this website to read the bmp : https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/how-to-read-and-create-barcode-images-using-c-and-zxing-net/?force_isolation=true

Comment: I am currently using PrivId library to read the barcode, reading it is not exactly my issue here

Comment: Isn't reading a bar code getting the string?  The string is an ASCII representation of the Bars.